# Push code from Github.com to local server

Tags: git, github

I am just getting started in Git and I am trying to automate some system admin tasks.

I have a repo in Github.com and after making proper changes and merging to the main branch I have to PUSH it to the local server (not PULL from local server).

Is it possible to PUSH the main brach in Github.com to local server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your local server is **not** your local working directory of the project, where you change your code.

In that case, you can't directly take changes from GitHub and push them to your local server, but what you can do is setup [multiple remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes). That way you can push to GitHub and your local server independently (which can be automated).

---

Ex:

```
# Adding a new remote
$ git remote add localserver <url>
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/user/repo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/repo (push)
localserver <url> (fetch)
localserver <url> (push)

# Pushing to GH and local server
$ git push origin master
$ git push localserver master
```